# Restricted sudo access for support staff

Tags: sudo

We have some L1 support staff who need to manage user accounts, etc. but we'd prefer to restrict them from having full sudo access.

Is that practical? I wasn't able to find any useful in Google or site searches.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is just the normal case.

> The `/etc/sudoers` file controls who can run what commands as what users on what machines and can also control special things

You can edit the `sudoers` file to your needs, run:

```bash
sudo visudo
```

Make sure to read and understand the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers) about it.

Comment: Lovely, thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on pLumo's answer, the typical line you would want to add to the `/etc/sudoers` file (using `visudo`) to manage user and group accounts would be this:

```
name ALL=(ALL) /usr/sbin/adduser /usr/sbin/addgroup /usr/sbin/deluser /usr/sbin/delgroup
```

This will allow the user with username `name` to run the four commands specified (`adduser`, `addgroup`, `deluser`, `delgroup`).

You could also allow access to the utilities `useradd`, `usermod`, `userdel`, `groupadd` and `groupdel` - but these are more low-level utilities that may or may not be needed for the tasks.

Comment: Lovely, thanks very much.

Comment: @Luke, please upvote if you find the answer useful.